# Propriedade Hover do css não esta cobrindo o item do lado

Tags: css, html5, css-hover

Tenho dois retangulos da tela com informações dentro. Utilizei a propriedade Hover do CSS, para que quando o mouse seja passado em cima, o retangulo aumente de tamanho. Porém ele não cobre o retangulo que esta do lado, as informações ficam abaixo. Como posso fazer para que quando passar o mouse por cima, o objeto retangulo cubra o outro que esta do lado, mostrando assim todas as informações.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #tudo{
        margin: 50px 0px 0px 33px;
    }
    .position-box{
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        height: 160px;
        background-color: #D9D9F3;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .estilo:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    }
    a:link, a:visited, a:active{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }
    .titulo{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .estilo_tab{
        position: absolute;
        padding-right: -30px;
        width: -60px;
        border-color: #000;
    }
    td{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    }
</style>

<body>

<div id="tudo">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="position-box estilo">
            <span class="titulo">
                <p>Teste Dashboard</p>
            </span>
            <table border="1" class="estilo_tab">
                <tr>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="tudo">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="position-box estilo">
            <span class="titulo">
                <p>Teste Dashboard</p>
            </span>
            <table border="1" class="estilo_tab">
                <tr>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acrescente a propriedade `z-index: 1` ao estilo `.estilo:hover {`. Assim o elemento com o estado `:hover` sempre ficará por cima do outro.

Execute e tela cheia:

```css
#tudo{
        margin: 50px 0px 0px 33px;
    }
    .position-box{
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        height: 160px;
        background-color: #D9D9F3;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .estilo:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    a:link, a:visited, a:active{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }
    .titulo{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .estilo_tab{
        position: absolute;
        padding-right: -30px;
        width: -60px;
        border-color: #000;
    }
    td{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="tudo">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="position-box estilo">
            <span class="titulo">
                <p>Teste Dashboard</p>
            </span>
            <table border="1" class="estilo_tab">
                <tr>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="tudo">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="position-box estilo">
            <span class="titulo">
                <p>Teste Dashboard</p>
            </span>
            <table border="1" class="estilo_tab">
                <tr>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                    <td>Teste </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                    <td>info</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado sam. Me ajudou muito.